# Subquery grouping in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an issue with a stored procedure where I'm trying to get the total overdue invoices per customer, but this is resulting in an unexpected result.

The table I'm querying looks like this:

```
| ClientId | IsNewInvoice | DueDate    |
+----------+--------------+------------+
| 220      | 1            | 2019/07/17 |
| 221      | 1            | 2019/07/15 |
| 222      | 1            |            |
```

Query looks like this

```
SELECT 
    ClientId,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM Invoices
     WHERE DueDate IS NOT NULL 
       AND DueDate <> ''            
       AND CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, DueDate), 102) < 
        CAST((STR(YEAR(GETDATE())) + '/' +
              STR(MONTH(GETDATE())) + '/' +
              STR(DAY(GETDATE()))) AS DATETIME)) AS overdueInvoices,
    SUM(isNewInvoice) AS total
FROM 
    Invoices
GROUP BY
    clientId
```

But somehow, I get the following results after running my query where I have double the amount of overdue invoices than each client has a total:

```
| clientId | overdueInvoices | total |
+----------+-----------------+-------+
| 220      | 2               | 1     |
| 221      | 2               | 1     |
| 222      | 2               | 1     |
```

I'm guessing I need to group by clientId for the overdue invoice but SQL complains that

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

When I use the following query:

```
SELECT 
    ClientId,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM Invoices
     WHERE DueDate IS NOT NULL 
       AND DueDate <> ''            
       AND CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, DueDate), 102) < 
           CAST((STR(YEAR(GETDATE())) + '/' +
                 STR(MONTH(GETDATE())) + '/' +
                 STR(DAY(GETDATE()))) AS DATETIME)  
     GROUP BY clientId) AS overdueInvoices,
    SUM(isNewInvoice) as total
FROM 
    Invoices
GROUP BY
    clientId
```

Comment: You seem to be reporting conflicting things.  First you said you _do_ get output, but that output is not what you expect, then you said you _don't_ get output, but get an error message instead.  What is actually happening?

Comment: That SQL and that error aren't related. That subquery can only ever return 1 row; and it is using `COUNT` without a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry you are right, that part is confusing. I get the error after I try to group by clientId under the subquery for overdueInvoices. Ill update the question

Comment: You need to use a correlated subquery, not a `GROUP BY`. But i can't see why you not a correlated subquery at all; seem like you'd be far better off with a conditional aggregate (like Gordan has done).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you converting to strings to compare dates?  Why are you using a subquery?

It seems like you want:

```
SELECT ClientId,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DueDate < CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as overdueInvoice,
       SUM(isNewInvoice) as total
FROM Invoices i
GROUP BY clientId;
```

This assumes that `DueDate` is already `date`/`datetime` (or similar), because on the conversion you do.  If it is a string, you should fix the data.  You can also convert to a date value in the query.